# How to optimize this Scala code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Scala, curious how to optimize this code.  What I have is an RDD loaded from Spark.  It's a tab delimited dataset. I want to combine the first column with the second column, and append it as a new column to the end of the dataset, with a "-" separating the two.

For example:
`column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3`

becomes

`column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3\tcolumn1-column2`

```
val f = sc.textFile("path/to/dataset")

f.map(line => if (line.split("\t").length > 1) 
        line.split("\t") :+ line.split("\t")(0)+"-"+line.split("\t")(1) 
    else 
        Array[String]()).map(a => a.mkString("\t")
 )
 .saveAsTextFile("output/path")
```

Comment: I'd start by doing that string `split` only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
f.map{ line =>
  val cols = line.split("\t")
  if (cols.length > 1) line + "\t" + cols(0) + "-" + cols(1)
  else line
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah change it from map{ to map( allowed me to set a val inside.